# Action Script 3.0 preloading bar

Tags: actionscript-3, action

I would like to if someone to know why i have so big delay in my flash main file when I go to test the preloading bar with duble control enter...
I have enable the status report file in flash wich say to me was I load a class
(AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame) but i dont link any class in my file..
Please help me Thanks!

Comment: You may need to give some more information. What 's your coding environment, are you using Flash CS for instance? You have a preloader , showing progress for what? How do you instantiate your preloader etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your classes are being exported and linked to the very first frame, and in that case the preloader will take a long time depending on the content.

I would suggest you look into the preloader template of flashdevelop to get started.

Comment: That the same problem I have it with the flash cs5 professional but if i change the frame where classes loaded nothing is change the same white screen still there.